# Ajax requests are served by a single server thread?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

I made a simple ajax framework at http://www.iqp.vn and I allow users to make many ajax requests or cancel them.

But from testing I see that, when user make an ajax request that do some thing that takes up a long time like copying/writting a large text file, subsequent requests will wait until the first one is done before them are executed. On the client I see that the second request although it performes very quick processing always return after the 1st "big" request is done.

I also use hidden form (iframe) submission to allow user to upload files in ajax style, and when user upload a large file, and cancel the request (== reset the iframe on the client), and click to generate another request, I see that the later request always wait for the first upload request to finish.

Can any one help me with this please, I thought using ajax, and (if possible) with multithreaded processing on server, I can get some very nice effects on client.

Comment: Please post some of your code to help get an answer....

Comment: I'll public my code after some refactoring later

Comment: Maybe when I found this problem my network is too bad, now it works as expected. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax requests are treated like normal requests. You should check:

- Is a ajax call waiting for the other to finish before calling (client side)?
- Do you implement any locking mechanism on the server?
- May be all the threads in the thread pool are busy with other requests

Just for reference, this jQuery plugin can upload many files simultaneously: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: I make ajax calls independently, no waiting on client side. No locks on server, my site is new so might no be overloaded. My upload code (iframe & hidden form) is similar to ajax form jquery plugin. I thought that each web requests is serviced by a new thread so the upload request can't block other requests. [link to upload](http://www.iqp.vn/#!mh=&mh_lh=Examples/LeftTree&mh_rh=Examples/UpdatePanel) if you upload a file here, then immediately abort it by click the red cross button, then click on a link to load something, it will be blocked by the upload request :(

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour will depend on the configuration of your web server.  If you've only got one thread assigned to the application pool then that thread will be servicing every request.